# How to add a localized image into an app resources?

Tags: android, android-resources

I'm trying to add localized image assets like in the tutorial: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html

I tried hard and searched for how to do it but I can't find how.

On the Android project tree, there's an option to create a new directory, I create one with my desired language. The directory is not visible on the Android project view, but is visible on the Project view tree.

After this I try to configure a new image asset, but there's no option to specify the language.

There's also the option to create a new resource file, this has an option to select the language but has no option to create image assets.

So, how do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your link was right... (emphasis added)

> To add support for more locales, create additional directories inside `res/`. Each directory's name should adhere to the following format:
>
> ```
> <resource type>-b+<language code>[+<country code>]
> ```
>
> For example, `values-b+es/` contains string resources for locales with the language code `es`. Similarly, **`mipmap-b+es+ES/` contains icons for locales with the `es` language code and the `ES` country code**

So, you can add your localized images under some `res/drawable-b+CODE` or `res/mipmap-b+CODE` directory.

> I try to configure a new image asset, but there's no option to specify the language

Perhaps not, but that doesn't stop you from moving a file into the proper location.

Comment: Ok, but the IDE should provide a feature to do it, if there's a feature to help translate strings why the images asset don't have it? Is it missing or is that I can't find it?

Comment: I don't use Android Studio, so can't help you there